# Space between variables in a large equation and reduce size of powers?

Tags: spacing, equations

```
\begin{equation}
\resizebox{.8\hsize}{!}{$<\mathscr{F}>=\frac{\int_\Gamma d^{3\!\!N}\!\!\!q\, d^{3\!\!N}\!p\, \rho(q, p) \mathscr{F}(q, p)} {\underbrace{\int_\Gamma d^{3\!N}\! \!\!q\,  d^{3\!N}\!\!\!\!\!p\, \, \rho(q, p)}_{Normalisation factor}}
$}
\end{equation}
```

This is the code I am using but it looks quite messy and I am really unsure what options are available to structure it better. Thank you in advance.

Comment: it would be useful to have a fully compilable example, starting with the `\documentclass`, so we know what sort of space you have to work with.

Comment: If you find yourself putting `\resizebox` or `\!` in a formula you should ask yourself if you _really_ intend to do that:-) Why have you made the 3 overlap the N??

Answer (score 6):

Why you need to reduce the space is not clear to me.  Even in a two column document it fits without problem.  On the other hand you are doing a lot to disrupt LaTeX's layout.
There are a couple of problems with your set-up

- angle brackets should be input `\langle...\rangle` not `<...>`
- the integrals in the top and bottom of the `\frac` should be uniform, below I have used `\displaystyle` to force the numerator to be bigger, conversely you could use `\textstyle` inside the denominator to make it like the original numerator
- the text under the brace should be set with `\text{...}`, otherwise you get crazy spacing

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \langle \mathscr{F} \rangle =
  \frac
    {\displaystyle \int_\Gamma d^{3N}q\, d^{3N}p\, \rho(q, p) \mathscr{F}(q, p)}
    {\underbrace{\int_\Gamma d^{3N}q\,  d^{3N}p\, \rho(q, p)}_{\text{Normalisation factor}}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Almost the same as mine; however, perhaps `d^{\,3N}\!p` would help in improving the formula: the `3` clashes with the stem of the `d`, while `p` is a bit too far from the exponent (the same for the `q`, of course).

Comment: @egreg Your taste is always impeccable, but I don't completely agree.  There is no overlap between the `d` and the `3`, although they are close.  The `\,` after `p` is enough visual off-set for me for a first run; at a final production stage I might consider tweaking it.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two solutions,; one of them uses tools from `nccmath`to have mediumsized formulae (~80 % of `\displaystyle`). In addition, I replaced `<\mathscr F>` with `\langle\mathscr F\rangle`, as I suspect it's the correct notation – but maybe I'm wrong.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\newcommand\dint{\displaystyle\int}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
 \langle\mathscr{F}\rangle=\frac{\dint_\Gamma d^{3N}\mkern-4mu q\, d^{3N}\mkern-4mu p\, \rho(q, p) \mathscr{F}(q, p)} {\underbrace{\int_\Gamma d^{3N}\mkern-4mu q\, d^{3N}\mkern-4mu p\,\rho(q, p)}_{\text{Normalisation factor}}} \\[3ex]
 \langle\mathscr{F}\rangle=
 \frac{\medmath{\int_\Gamma d^{3N}\mkern-4mu q\, d^{3N}\mkern-4mu p\, \rho(q, p) \mathscr{F}(q, p)} } {\underbrace{\medmath{\int_\Gamma d^{3N}\mkern-4mu q\, d^{3N}\mkern-4mu p\,\rho(q, p)}}_{\text{Normalisation factor}}}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @David Carlisle: But who stole the tarts?

Comment: probably an oversight -- the `p` is closer to the `\rho` in the denominator than it is in the numerator, both examples.

Comment: Right. I  didn't check coherence between numerator and denominator. It's now corrected. Thank you for pointing that.